# php unlink a div or place div in variable

Tags: php, html, variables, unlink

Ok, bottom line is. I've got an image gallery on my website. I can upload and retrieve images to my Mysqli database. The multiple images are placed into placeholder divs, which shows a little box around the image and the name of the image. I've got a Delete function per image that works with PHP unlink. But whenever I delete the image, the box and name of the image still appear.

Is there a way to not just unlink the image, but the entire div so the placeholder will delete entirely? Or, is there a way to place a div inside a variable, because I know how to unlink a variable containing multiple fles. Here is my code

The div is called "media".

```
    <ul class="media-list">
      <?php
      include "config.php"; //database connection
      $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM upload_data");
      while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()):
      ?> 
    <div class="media">    

   <a class="media-left" href="#">
   <!--  <img src="upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>"> -->
   </a>
        <div class="img"><?php if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) 

            {
        echo '<a href="delete.php?id=&nm=<?php echo $row[\'file_name\'] ?>">Delete</a>';} ?>

  <a target="_blank" href="javascript:popImage('upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>','<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>')">
    <img width="300" height="200" src="upload/<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['file_name'] ?>">
            </a>  
        </div>
        </div>

    <?php
      endwhile;
      ?>
```

Here's also the unlink code if you're wondering:

```
<?php
include "config.php";


if(isset($_GET['id'])):
  $hap = unlink('upload/'.$_GET['nm']);
  if($hap){
     $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM upload_data WHERE id_upload=?");
     $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);

     $id = $_GET['id'];

     if($stmt->execute()):
          echo "<script>location.href='gallery.php'</script>";
     else:
          echo "<script>alert('".$stmt->error."')</script>";
     endif;
  } else{
    echo "<script>alert('No Delete File From Harddisk')</script>";
    echo "<script>location.href='gallery.php'</script>";
  }
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file is deleted correctly.

But you're passing wrong parameter into the SQL query. `$id` is not defined on the line `$stmt->bind_param('s', $id);`

Supposing the `id_upload` column is integer. Replace the line with this:

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', (int)$_GET['id']);
```